# Use Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter in Cypher Query Neo4j

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher

Is there a built in way which creates Cyhper `WHERE` condition or a `MATCH` condition form `Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter` ?

I uses `Neo4j.Driver` not `Neo4jClient`.

I can do it myself with [ExpressionVisitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor?view=netframework-4.7.2) or just walk all the expression in the tree recursively. But It would be great if where there are any support for it already?

Some example what wold be great result:

```
 c#: CypherWhere<Person>( p => p.Age > 30 ) ==>
 Cypher: WHERE p.Age > 30
```

or

```
 c#: CypherWhere<Person>( p => p.Age > 30 & p.Sex == Sex.Female  ) ==>
 Cypher: WHERE p.Age > 30 AND p.Sex = 1
```

If there is no any support, and I have to is from scratch, then it would be grate if somebody links the similar functionality which ask from JSON, because the syntax and the meaning is little but similar.

Maybe the `Neo4jClient` driver has a similar code in it?

Comment: According to this blog https://neo4j.com/blog/dotnet-developers-neo4jclient-is-back/ The answer is not yet.

Comment: Thx for the info. It is a 3 years old blogpost, Waht do you think, is there any changes according this question?

Comment: I searched the site, but nothing else came up with support for `linq`